# Percentage calculations with filters and column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a new column in Microsoft Access/SQL but the new column should be calculated with a filtering.

If my table looks like below:

```
Name Value Type
A      5     X
A      4     I
A      3     P
A      1     B
B      1     X
B      8     I
B      7     P
```

Is it posisble to do a Group by Name and create a calculation like:

`Value(Where Type=X) + Value(Where Type=I) / Sum(Value)` ?

And return

```
Name CustomCol
A       0.64
B       0.56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pretty much as you described:

```
select name,
       sum(iff(type in ("X", "I"), value, 0.0)) / sum(value)
from t
group by name;
```